# Git commit button disabled on pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm, commit

I decided to upload my code to git. Created repository and pushed through Windows cmd.
Now I want to work directly via Pycharm.
I logged into my github account.
When I change a file its name becomes blue (I know it means that it's different from the version on git).

I want to commit and push it, but the commit button is disabled. What am I doing wrong?

[image: commoit and add buttons are disabled]

Comment: What do you mean by "the commit button is disabled"? You mean that it doesn't allow you to press it or that the "add" and "commit file" buttons don't do what you expect them to do?

Comment: I meant that both buttons were gray (instead of white) and didn't allow me to press them.
But after a while it changed and I could. I'm not sure what caused it.
any way, problem solved

Comment: Experienced the same (Pycharm Pro 2023.2.1). Therefore voted up.

Comment: I recognized that I could navigate within the IDE so it obviously didn't hang. However, I could not open another project, nor commit nor close Pycharm. So I killed all instances found with `ps -aux | grep pycharm` and restarted the IDE. Then the problem was gone.